# Unable to persist data between builds using RestKit 0.20

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

So I've recently switched over to the RestKit core data implementation and am having some issues persisting data between builds / application launches - i.e. if I create an object and save it it works fine as long as the app remains open but as soon as I close the simulator and rebuild the data is gone. I did some research on this and found a number of StackOverflow threads like this:

[Entities saved to RKManagedObjectStore's mainQueueManagedObjectContext disappear on next build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193025/entities-saved-to-rkmanagedobjectstores-mainqueuemanagedobjectcontext-disappear)

Offering for the most part the same solution - switching from save: to saveToPersistentStore: - but unfortunately even with this change my saves still aren't persisting. I would greatly appreciate any help!

My App Delegate, basically configured exactly as can be found in the basic RestKit tutorial:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"appName" ofType:@"momd"]];
   // NOTE: Due to an iOS 5 bug, the managed object model returned is immutable.
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] mutableCopy];
    RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

   // Initialize the Core Data stack
    [managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

    NSPersistentStore __unused *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addInMemoryPersistentStore:&error];
    NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store: %@", error);

    [managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

   // Set the default store shared instance
    [RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];

   // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    LoginVC *controller = (LoginVC *) navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
    return YES;
}
```

And the code actually creating the NSManagedObject object:

```
- (void) theSaveButtonOnTheAddDayVCWasTapped:(AddDaytimeVC *)controller{
    [controller.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if([[controller.activityDescriptionTextField text] length] > 0){
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
        Daytime *daytime = [context insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Daytime"];
        daytime.activityDescription = [controller.activityDescriptionTextField text];
        daytime.thoughts = [controller.thoughtsTextField text];
        NSError *error;
        if (![context saveToPersistentStore:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error saving context");
        }
        [self reloadArrayWithCurrentViewActivityType:@"Daytime"];
        [[self tableView] reloadData];
    }
}
```

I'm passing the mainQueueManagedObjectContext between views via the standard:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;
```

set in prepareForSegue. I also recently made a minor model changes (added a field) and regenerated the model objects if this might be of any help... I'm unfortunately not entirely sure if it was working as expected before then or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone was curious, this turned out to be rather straight forward. The whole "in memory" persistent store had me thrown off from the get-go but I didn't think the tutorial would use such a temporary example... I was wrong about that :-).

In my app delegate added:

```
NSString *path = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Fringe.sqlite"];
```

changed the persistentStore to:

```
  NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:path fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:[self optionsForSqliteStore] error:&error];
```

and added:

```
- (id)optionsForSqliteStore {
return @{
         NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES,
         NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES
         };
}
```

to configure the SQLite store. All is well now